# sed - insert a string with backslash at a specific line number

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file which contains multiple latex equations like this :

```
...

\begin{equation}
\beq{x}=x^{1}\beq{e_{1}}+x^{2}\beq{e_{2}}+x^{3}\beq{e_{3}}
\end{equation}

...

\begin{equation}
\beq{y}=y^{1}\beq{e_{1}}+y^{2}\beq{e_{2}}+y^{3}\beq{e_{3}}
\end{equation}

...
```

I want to insert just before the "`\end{equation}`" the string "`\tag{number}`" where I can successfully get `number` variable.

To insert this string at the line identified by "`$(($line)-1)`", I do :

```
gsed -i "$(($line)-1)i \tag{$number}" file
```

But I get only :

```
...

\begin{equation}
\beq{x}=x^{1}\beq{e_{1}}+x^{2}\beq{e_{2}}+x^{3}\beq{e_{3}}
tag{1}
\end{equation}

...

\begin{equation}
\beq{y}=y^{1}\beq{e_{1}}+y^{2}\beq{e_{2}}+y^{3}\beq{e_{3}}
tag{2}
\end{equation}

...
```

As you can see, I can't print the backslash character at the beginning of "\tag" string

I tried with :

```
gsed -i "$(($line)-1)i '\'tag{$number}" file
```

or

```
gsed -i "$(($line)-1)i \\tag{$number}" file
```

but no good results,

if someone could see what's wrong ...

Thanks

PS: I am on MacOS X, that's why I used `gsed`

Answer (score 0):

You need five slashes:

```
gsed -i "$(($line)-1)i \\\\\tag{$number}" file
```

Let me explain starting with a single quoted command:

```
gsed -i '1i \\\test'
```

You would need three slashes in that case:

The first one delimits the `i` command with the text to be inserted, the second one escapes the slash itself because otherwise it would get expanded as `\t`. The third, now escaped, slash, will get inserted as literal `\` at the start of the new line.

If we additionally using double quotes to enclose the command,

```
gsed -i "1i\\\\\test"
```

the string will get additionally subject of parsing by the shell. Both escaping slashes from the single quoted command, would therefore need to get escaped as well. This makes 5 slashes.

---

So far so good. But since you are interpolating shell variables into the command, you need to make sure that slashes in them would get escaped as well.

Comment: This doesn't work, I get : \begin{equation}
\beq{x}=x^{1}\beq{e_{1}}+x^{2}\beq{e_{2}}+x^{3}\beq{e_{3}}
        ag{1}
\end{equation}, i.e a tabulation and without backslash and 't' characters

Comment: Nice. Happy escaping! :)